# CSS style being crossed out because of media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So in this little fiddle I made, I'm trying to change the max-height to 20em when `.menuToggle` is clicked, I'm doing this by toggling a class. The class gets toggled but in chrome developer tools the style is crossed out. I'm assuming this has something to do with the media query but not entirely sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :).
https://jsfiddle.net/kakbxak0/

```
@media screen and max-width 1024px{
  .navBar ul li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
  }

  .navBar>ul {
    max-height:0;
  }

  .showing {
   max-height:20em;
  }

  header {
   text-align:center;
  }

  .menuToggle {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a specificity Problem. The Specificy of a Class and an Element/Pseudo-Element is higher than just a class.

So you just need to make the .solving selector more specific. E.g.

- ul.solving
- .navbar .solving
- !important

If you don't know the specificity you can check on https://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `!important` after the 20em in the `.showing` class. I believe the problem is you're adding style to a tag which takes precedence over a class. I could be wrong with the logic but adding `!important` was tested and works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".menuToggle").click(function(){
  $(".navBar > ul").toggleClass("showing");
});

});
```

```css
header{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #5e99f5;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12.5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navBar>ul{
  background-color: #3d6db7;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.navBar li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navBar a, .menuToggle{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.menuToggle{
  width: 100%;
  background: #3861a0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .navBar ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .showing{
    max-height: 20em!important;
  }
  .navBar>ul{
    max-height: 0em;
  }


  header{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .menuToggle{
    display: block;
  }

}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<body>
 <header>
  Title
 </header>
 <nav class="navBar">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="menuToggle">Menu</div>
 </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `.showing` with `.navBar>ul.showing` see below

```
.navBar ul.showing{
  max-height: 20em;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".menuToggle").click(function(){
  $(".navBar > ul").toggleClass("showing");
});

});
```

```css
header{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #5e99f5;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12.5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navBar>ul{
  background-color: #3d6db7;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.navBar li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navBar a, .menuToggle{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.menuToggle{
  width: 100%;
  background: #3861a0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .navBar ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navBar>ul{
    max-height: 0em;
  }

  .navBar>ul.showing{
    max-height: 20em;
  }

  header{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .menuToggle{
    display: block;
  }

}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<body>
 <header>
  Title
 </header>
 <nav class="navBar">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="menuToggle">Menu</div>
 </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong media query, Please looket this

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
          .navBar ul li {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            width:100%;
            text-align:center;
            padding:15px;
          }

          .navBar>ul {
            max-height:0;
          }

          .showing {
           max-height:20em;
          }

          header {
           text-align:center;
          }

          .menuToggle {
            display:block;
          }
        }
```